# Getting null when I print arguments.callee.caller is null in other than IE browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am making use of global exceptions by using `window.onerror` method. I am trying to get the function name by using `arguments.callee.caller` in IE. But in chrome and all other browsers it is null. I googled a lot. But I did not get any results. How can I get the value of caller in chrome/mozilla. Please suggest me. I gave sample piece of code given below.

```
window.onerror = function (msg, url, line, col, error) {
        debugger;
        // Note that col & error are new to the HTML 5 spec and may not be 
        // supported in every browser.  It worked for me in Chrome.
        var extra = !col ? '' : '\ncolumn: ' + col;
        extra += !error ? '' : '\nerror: ' + error;

        LineNumber = line;
        ColumnNumber = col;
        ErrorDescription = error.stack;
        //console.log(ErrorDescription);
        ErrorString = msg;
        var now = new Date();
        var datetime = now.getFullYear() + '/' + (now.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + now.getDate();
        ErrorDateTime = datetime + ' ' + now.getHours() + ':' + now.getMinutes() + ':' + now.getSeconds();

        // You can view the information in an alert to see things working like this:
        //alert("Error: " + msg + "\nurl: " + url + "\nline: " + line + extra);

        var FilePath = window.location.pathname;
        PageName = FilePath.split("/").pop();

        var ExceptionFunctionName = window.onerror.caller;
        if (ExceptionFunctionName != undefined && ExceptionFunctionName != null) {
            ExceptionFunctionName = ExceptionFunctionName.substr('function '.length);
            MethodName = ExceptionFunctionName.substr(0, ExceptionFunctionName.indexOf('{'));
        }
        capture();
        var suppressErrorAlert = true;
        // If you return true, then error alerts (like in older versions of 
        // Internet Explorer) will be suppressed.
        //return suppressErrorAlert;
    }
```

And my calling function is given below.

```
 function ExceptionFunction() {
      var Test = testvar / 5;
  }
```

Comment: I'm afraid the only thing you can do is to parse `error.stack` (via RegExp)...unfortunately the string-representation is not standardized an depends on the browser

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `window.onerror.caller` you need to use `arguments.callee.caller`

BR,
Saar

Comment: When I tried this in IE its working. But in other browsers it doesn't work and returns null .Please suggest me other alternative if you have.

Comment: But window.onerror function Returns null in Chrome because its call on When error occured in Current document.Please suggest me.